# define dynamic range in vba

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have the following problem:

I am trying to set the range client equal to a dynamically changing range.

In column AI, starting from cell 131, I have a list of clients, which varies in length depending on the years I download data for. I would like to set the range named client equal to this variable range. My code so far is:

```
Sub range()

Dim client As range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim startingcell As Long

Set startingcell = range("AI131")
lastrow = Cells(Row.Count, startingcell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Set client = range(startingcell, Cells(lastrow, startingcells.Column))

End Sub
```

It is not working though, any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `Dim startingcell As Long` and that should be `as Range`

Comment: `Row.Count` >> `Rows.Count`,  `startingcells.Column` >> `startingcell.Column`

Comment: @TimWilliams i missed the `row` to `rows` when copying that down for an answer.  nice catch

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've an error with dimensioning and use of variables not being correct.

This will utilize only `As Range` which should help resolve the issue:

```
Dim startcell As Range, endcell As Range, client As Range

Set startcell = Cells(131, "AI")
Set endcell = Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp)
Set client = Range(startcell, endcell)
```